# Replacing value not in list in Pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy

Say I have a data frame in Python.

If I want to replace all values in the say, the Size column that are **not** 'M' or 'S' or 'L' with nan, how do I do so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's the best way, but I'd write a function and apply it to the df['size']:

```
def rename_size(size):
    if size not in ['M','S','L']:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return size
df['size']= df['size'].apply(rename_size)
```